# Speed up data reading in R

Tags: r, linux, io, cut

I have the following line in my `R` code:

```
pipeline=sprintf("cut -f %i-%i %s", jcol1, jcol2, fname)
Ys <- as.matrix(read.table(pipe(pipeline)))
```

which takes about 3 seconds. Now, when I hardcode the associated `cut` line into my `Linux` terminal and pipe to `/dev/null` as:

```
time cut -f 2-5000 filename.txt > /dev/null
```

I find that this takes 0.631 seconds which tells me that it does not take long to actually *read* the file.

What aspect of my `R` code is taking so long and how can I improve the speed on this?

Comment: I am not a linux expert but my guess would be that read.table and as.matrix would add some overhead as R does a lot of processing to "understand" the data, determine the right fields, read into memory etc.

Comment: For starters you might try `readr::read_table` which will be faster than `read.table`.  That being said, I think that Rohit Das's comment is the reason you're seeing a relative slowdown

Comment: Try  comparing with: `library(data.table); fread(pipeline)`

Comment: or system cache could be affecting the read rates. Try running each 2-3 times in both environments. Good luck.